# Assistance request for (psycopg2.DatabaseError) Connection timed out

Tags: python, postgresql, sqlalchemy

I am following the install instructions for the security utility opencve which imports data into a postgresql database:

https://docs.opencve.io/installation/manual/

I have followed all of the instructions including creating the 5G swap file. All tables create, no problems, however, the data import fails at this step:

```
opencve import-data
```

I receive the below errors referring to a timeout time and time again. Despite straw clutching which includes disabling the firewall, searching for any postgresql timeout parameters, creating a large swap file and attempting the install on another server, as well as verifying that psycopg2-binary is installed, I still hit the same problem in the same spot.

The full errors displayed are below but I believe the main part is:

**File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 725, in do_executem
cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.DatabaseError: could not receive data from server: Connection timed out**

If I look at that psycopg2.py file, this is the block of code with line 725 being the last line:

```
   def do_executemany(self, cursor, statement, parameters, context=None):
        if self.psycopg2_batch_mode:
            extras = self._psycopg2_extras()
            extras.execute_batch(cursor, statement, parameters)
        else:
            cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
```

If this is a genuine timeout somewhere I can't see where. The connection is good as the tables get created in the earlier part of the import-data command.

This is the section that is repeatedly failing.

```
#####################
Importing CPE list...
#####################
[*] Downloading https://nvd.nist.gov/feeds/xml/cpe/dictionary/official-cpe-dictionary_v2.3.xml.gz... (done in 1.31s).
[*] Parsing XML elements... (done in 269.254s).
[*] Creating list of mappings... (done in 330.919s).
[*] Inserting Vendors and Products...Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1224, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 725, in do_executem
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
psycopg2.DatabaseError: could not receive data from server: Connection timed out

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/local/bin/opencve", line 11, in <module>
    sys.exit(cli())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 829, in __call__
    return self.main(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 782, in main
    rv = self.invoke(ctx)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1259, in invoke
    return _process_result(sub_ctx.command.invoke(sub_ctx))
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 1066, in invoke
    return ctx.invoke(self.callback, **ctx.params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opencve/commands/__init__.py", line 39, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/decorators.py", line 21, in new_func
    return f(get_current_context(), *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/flask/cli.py", line 412, in decorator
    return __ctx.invoke(f, *args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/click/core.py", line 610, in invoke
    return callback(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opencve/commands/imports/__init__.py", line 42, in import_data
    cpe.run(vendors)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/opencve/commands/imports/cpe.py", line 63, in run
    db.session.bulk_insert_mappings(Vendor, mappings["vendors"].values())
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/scoping.py", line 162, in do
    return getattr(self.registry(), name)(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2790, in bulk_insert_mappings
    render_nulls,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2880, in _bulk_save_mappings
    transaction.rollback(_capture_exception=True)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/langhelpers.py", line 68, in __exit__
    compat.reraise(exc_type, exc_value, exc_tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 129, in reraise
    raise value
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/session.py", line 2874, in _bulk_save_mappings
    render_nulls,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 102, in _bulk_insert
    bookkeeping=return_defaults,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/orm/persistence.py", line 1066, in _emit_insert_statements
    c = cached_connections[connection].execute(statement, multiparams)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 988, in execute
    return meth(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/sql/elements.py", line 287, in _execute_on_connection
    return connection._execute_clauseelement(self, multiparams, params)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1107, in _execute_clauseelement
    distilled_params,
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1248, in _execute_context
    e, statement, parameters, cursor, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1466, in _handle_dbapi_exception
    util.raise_from_cause(sqlalchemy_exception, exc_info)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 383, in raise_from_cause
    reraise(type(exception), exception, tb=exc_tb, cause=cause)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/util/compat.py", line 128, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/engine/base.py", line 1224, in _execute_context
    cursor, statement, parameters, context
  File "/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/sqlalchemy/dialects/postgresql/psycopg2.py", line 725, in do_executem
    cursor.executemany(statement, parameters)
sqlalchemy.exc.DatabaseError: (psycopg2.DatabaseError) could not receive data from server: Connection timed out

[SQL: INSERT INTO vendors (id, created_at, updated_at, name) VALUES (%(id)s, now(), now(), %(name)s)]
[parameters: ({'id': UUID('a53ecce1-d16d-4ae5-a20d-3c93034b8d32'), 'name': 'openbsd'}, {'id': UUID('98176222-30ad-498c5a-4a3981bc068e'), 'name': 'freebsd'}, {'id': UUID('f734d65f-f55d-4a3d-a099-189d120bfa99'), 'name': 'bsdi'}, {'id'UID('eadb7068-c668-4981-9190-5aba1ce58d6c'), 'name': 'redhat'}, {'id': UUID('ec37138d-9dc9-432f-a6a4-a4d2e80770b1'),ame': 'caldera'}, {'id': UUID('523ea159-56bc-48c6-914f-1ebecd0f1120'), 'name': 'tritreal'}, {'id': UUID('287ac9fb-654751-a005-625b43059719'), 'name': 'sun'}, {'id': UUID('167edc67-f559-42fb-a501-f91e4114faed'), 'name': 'hp'}  ... diaying 10 of 28136 total bound parameter sets ...  {'id': UUID('2121a912-76a3-453f-8963-09c537f4bf78'), 'name': 'zend_feedback_tab_project'}, {'id': UUID('5f742c4f-3e37-486d-b5aa-80a92e9f0559'), 'name': 'zyzel'})]
(Background on this error at: http://sqlalche.me/e/4xp6)
```

I have opened a case for comment on the opencve git page but there has been no response so, hoping that someone may have some advice here please.

Comment: I'm not familiar with `opencve` but `psycopg2.connect` accepts a `connect_timeout` parameter that you may be able to adjust if you can trace back where it's being set.

Comment: In the past, I've also had to set the statement timeout using the following options='-c statement_timeout=N'. See https://iotespresso.com/how-to-configure-statement-timeout-in-psycopg2/

Comment: I have completed a grep from /usr/local/lib64/python3.6/site-packages/psycopg2 for psycopg2.connect with the following results: __init__.py:        conn = psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres password=secret")
__init__.py:        conn = psycopg2.connect(database="test", user="postgres", password="secret")
pool.py:        conn = psycopg2.connect(*self._args, **self._kwargs) and it seems no timeout is set I have tried to find if there is a default in the module. It does not appear so.

Comment: The documentation is not overly clear it (https://www.psycopg.org/docs/module.html) says you can use any of https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/libpq-connect.html#LIBPQ-PARAMKEYWORDS but doesn't mention what the default is if you don't supply it.

Comment: Plus in my experience, a connection timeout is caused by a problem such as an incorrect server name, DNS issue or if you're on AWS like me but haven't connected to the VPN. Usually, it either connects right away. It's the statement timeout that I find I sometimes have to change for long queries

Comment: What does PotgreSQL report in its log file?